# how to add a picture path on pubspec.yaml file on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have modified my `pubspec.yaml` file by adding the folder path of the picture that I want to add but I an error:

```
Running "flutter pub get" in drawer2...                         
Error on line 44, column 5 of pubspec.yaml: Expected a key while parsing a block mapping.

   ╷

44 │     assets :

   │     ^

   ╵

Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly.
Sending crash report to Google.
Crash report sent (report ID: 7f0c2ad768060692)
Crash report written to C:\Users\Mohamed bh\Desktop\files\flutter operations\drawer2\flutter_06.log;
please let us know at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.
```

//My pubspec.yaml code

flutter:

```
  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
    assets :
   - assets/
   # - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
   # - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

Running "flutter pub get" in drawer2...                         
Error on line 44, column 5 of pubspec.yaml: Expected a key while parsing a block mapping.

   ╷

44 │     assets :

   │     ^

   ╵

Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly.
Sending crash report to Google.
Crash report sent (report ID: 7f0c2ad768060692)
Crash report written to C:\Users\Mohamed bh\Desktop\files\flutter operations\drawer2\flutter_06.log;
please let us know at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should respect the indentation, it won't work if you add or remove even one space,
this is how you should do it:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/my_icon.png
    - assets/background.png
```

The best way is to copy/past it from the [official documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images).

Answer (score 1):

1. I have created assets/images folder in root of the project and
   placed icon.png and gplus.png images files in to it.
2. Then I have defined image resources in pubspec.yaml file like below image
   [image]
3. Then used image in project like below
   [image]